# SELECT via php script and directly via phpmyadmin = different output

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I've got two users with same points. Lets say 1 point for user id: `V.Rossi 46` and 1 point for user id: `testing`

in my ranking script.. they are disabled as:

```
1st. V.Rossi 46 (first place) -- > 1 point
2nd. testing (second place) -- > 1 point
3rd .... everyone else with 0 points or less.
```

the displaying query in the ranking script is selecting/ordering by points DESC

I've got another query to select that info and place it in another table and here is the problem ...
once the script is executed, it seems mysql is picking up `testing` as first place and I don't know why is that? The both queries are same. Just one display up to 25 rows and the update query is only select the top 1 and if required using `offset 1` for 2nd one and etc ...
**So what may cause to pick up them in different way?**

UPDATE **EXAMPLE:**

By executing a query via the phpmyadmin:

SELECT users_id FROM users ORDER BY daily_points desc limit 3

I get same results but in different order and by executing the same query on my ranking script. Why is that? I probably found the issue. Could it be caused by my displaying ranking code?

```
                <?
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach($users as $user)
                    {
                        echo '
                    <div class="row">'.(


                        (($i == '1')?'<div class="num_1"></div>':'').
                        (($i == '2')?'<div class="num_2"></div>':'').
                        (($i == '3')?'<div class="num_3"></div>':'').
                        (($i > '3')?'<div class="num">'.$i.'</div>':'')
.....
```

Comment: Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause MySQl doesn't guarantee the order in which results are returned. Even if you do specify one, MySQL will not guarantee the order where the ordered values are identical.

Comment: In both queries as mentioned already there is `ORDER BY` for `desc points` ... But on website ranking script having same points for first and second place its displayed in one way and by selecting the info frm the table, it appears to be different. Why is that my question and I am sorry but couldnt understand you what you mean?